# Flair bug - one of the side logos is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flair

As you can see on the screenshot below, on my combined flair the logo of Sports.SE is too big and is not fully displayed. IMO it's the same size as in the site-only flair.

[image: screenshot flair]

It seems that the bug is only with the Spots.SE logo, other beta sites are not affected

[image: onether screenshot]

Comment: looking into it

Comment: [Looks good to me](http://stackexchange.com/users/1524370/dirty-flow?tab=flair).

Comment: @Undo the same bug was on stackexchange.com too, which was fixed, you didn't see it because of caching (as always)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pushed out retina icons /sprites + the site's favicon.ico now has a 16px and a 32px icon, which the flair rendering didn't take into account.

Fixed in next build.

Comment: Yay! Retina icon!