# A51 flair has random large icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

On Area 51, several of the site icons now appear to be about twice normal size. This causes those at the end of the list to be cut off.  This appears to be the case everywhere this type of pseudo-flair is used (committed list, following list, created/edited).

Which flair are large appears to be constant, so it may be missing an explicit size specification on the image.

[image: Example of large flair]

Comment: possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217370/flair-bug-one-of-the-side-logos-is-too-big

Comment: @StevenV That is about the actual (site/SE) flair, this is the pseudo-flair that A51 uses

Comment: Also, that one is "status completed," and this is obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed on live site.

Comment: test test test can you hear me test